# How to get resourceLoader int Spring

Tags: java, spring

I run Spring in this way:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
```

Where `Main.class` is:

```
@SpringBootApplication()
public class Main {
   //some code here
}
```

In another module (it includes as separate jar library) I have instance of Spring ApplicationContext:

```
@Autowired
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

I need to know class, which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, to create new  ApplicationContext (In this example it is `Main.class`). How can I do it?

Comment: For one application which you want to run you should have one class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. Is your jar is just a library or separate application which also should be runnable?

Comment: This is just library.

Comment: In this case I guess in this case the `applicationContext` will be injected with application context of your main application which is using your library.